# C++ library for graphs with maximum common subgraph solver

Tags: libraries, c++, graph-theory

I'm looking for a convenient, free C++ library for graphs that include a solver for the maximum common subgraph (MCS) problem.

I'm aware of the
[Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)
and
[LEMON](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon)
, but neither includes an MCS solver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/694), Boost Graph Library added this feature around 3 years ago. The appropriate function (or set of functions) appears to be [this function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/doc/mcgregor_common_subgraphs.html) (`mcgregor_common_subgraphs`), which uses the McGregor algorithm.

Comment: I must have just missed it when browsing the TOC. I'll check it out and report back

Comment: It's pretty hard to find. I had to do a few Google searches to find it, and I think it'd be easy to miss when scanning the TOC, so no worries.